# Free IIS .NET Wiki

Tags: gratis, .net, wiki, windows-server

Running a Win2012 Server (IIS, .NET 4.5, MS SQL) server in our office. Looking to set up a wiki for our employees. What free wiki would be easy to set up?

Comment: What should the wiki be capable of (basic requirements)? Think of links, images, tables, code formatting … What should be used as "wiki language" (Markdown, MediaWiki, …)? Must it be extensible by plugins? Should it use a database, or "plain text files"? Any other requirements? Currently your question is quite vague, and could be closed as "too broad". So please [edit] it and add some more details. Thanks!

Comment: As alway, Wikimatrix should be your first stop. https://www.wikimatrix.org/wizard

Comment: Is there a particular reason you couldn't run PHP on your server? This would increase the number of options a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So, With out know fully what you need, I found [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177293/what-is-the-best-asp-net-wiki-out-there) which might help you find one you like.

The top two wikis on for the question are the following:

- [Roadkill .NET Wiki engine](https://github.com/roadkillwiki/roadkill)
- <s>[ScrewTurn Wiki](https://stw.codeplex.com/)</s> **(no longer under active development.)**

They both are open source and support plugins and themes.

Comment: Screw turn is not under active development and hasn't been for a while. That is not to say that is going to disappear imminently though ....

Answer (score 0):

By default you can actually deploy [MediaWiki](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/mediawiki-on-iis) on IIS.